# Android JUNIT testing stuck

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests

I'm new at JUnit tests, I'm trying to test database access through this code:

```
public class SeuticketTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Seuticket> {

    private Seuticket mActivity;

    public SeuticketTest(String name) {
        super("br.com.code.seuticket.android.view",Seuticket.class);
    setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = this.getActivity();
    }


    public void testTicketInsertion() {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket("123453", "Vip", new Date(), "Vila Country");
        PersistenceTicket persistence = new PersistenceTicket(mActivity);
        persistence.addTicket(ticket);
                       assertEquals(persistence.fetchTicket(ticket.getTicketCode()).getTicketCode(),ticket.getTicketCode());
    }
    public void testUserInsertion() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setPin("1234");
        user.setPhone("9241173");
        PersistenceUser persistence = new PersistenceUser(mActivity);
        persistence.addUser(user);
        assertEquals(persistence.fetchUser().getPin(), user.getPin());
    }

}
```

But my tests get stuck after complete the testTicketInsertion, the second test keep running forever, and sometimes before it run the tests this message shows at the console:
Test run failed: Process crashed.

Any ideas?
Hope to find an answer here.
Thanks people!

Comment: Any stacktrace in the console / debug log ? What happens when you run only the first test ? Only the second one ? When you change order ? Is it possible for you to test PersistenceTicket in isolation (providing a mock Activity or something ?) I would not be suprised if the persistence.fetchUser() method was the culprit, but you would have to debug it.

Comment: aparently the tests run at alphabetical order... doesnt matter te order that is written, sometimes appears at the console the error: Process crashed. Have no idea where it came from... i tried to erase the second method, and write another method, occours the same thing.

Comment: I get the same thing. @phtrivier, there is no logcat results, only the console for the tests saying Process crashed.

Answer (score 1):

I am brand new to JUnit testing in Android and ran into the same problem. Make sure you have the tearDown method overridden and are making the call to super.

```
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
```